# How can I write a function to accept a Fraction object in SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, swig, fractions

I'm writing an interface between Python and a our C++ video-processing library using SWIG. In python, I use the `Fraction` class to represent frame rate (e.g. NTFS24 = 24000/1001 FPS). The functionality in question is video transcoding, i.e. taking a video (or a stream of frames) input and producing a similar output. For that we need to specify the output (and sometimes input) frame rate.

Is there any way I can interface the Fraction class on the C++ (SWIG) side? From what I found around the Internet I should be able to pass a `tuple` to a `std::pair<int,int>` parameter, so that's my fallback plan, but is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: It's be pretty easy to define a corresponding fraction class in C++ and map the python one to that if it's what you wanted. What does the C++ library do already?

Comment: I updated the question to specify the functionality, the library does pretty much all we need but only takes a float FPS as of now.

If what you're saying is a mapping that would allow us to pass a `Fraction` object on the python side and get the corresponding object (of the `std::pair` or a custom class) on the C++, then that's probably what we want. Can you link some doc on how to do such a mapping? Thanks!

Comment: If the C++ function takes a float then you're stuck with passing it a float. I can write a typemap for fractions in SWIG but it won't get applied, or it'll have to convert to a float anyway if the C++ function only takes floats as inputs.

Comment: Don't worry about the float, I was going to make the change to make it take the `std::pair<int,int>` anyway, to give it at least the tuple interface! I didn't make it clear enough that the library is ours (and therefore I can change it if necessary), oops!

Comment: Ah ok, I'll write up an answer later today then hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together the following interface file to illustrate how wrapping a Fraction might work. In the end I decided to create my own fractions struct to hold the fractions on the C++ side, primarily because it's less ambiguous than using `std::pair<int, int>`. (I figured a pair of integers could also be a 2D coordinate, or a screen resolution or many other types, and stronger typing is a better thing for overload resolution etc.)

```
%module test

%{
#include <iostream> // Just for testing....

static PyObject *fractions_module = NULL;
%}

%init %{
  // Import the module we want
  fractions_module = PyImport_ImportModule("fractions");
  assert(fractions_module);
  // TODO: we should call Py_DECREF(fractions_module) when our module gets unloaded
%}

%typemap(in) const Fraction& (Fraction tmp) {
  // Input typemap for fraction: duck-type on attrs numerator, denominator
  PyObject *numerator = PyObject_GetAttrString($input, "numerator");
  PyObject *denominator = PyObject_GetAttrString($input, "denominator");

  int err = SWIG_AsVal_int(numerator, &tmp.numerator);
  assert(SWIG_IsOK(err)); // TODO: proper error handling
  err = SWIG_AsVal_int(denominator, &tmp.denominator);
  assert(SWIG_IsOK(err)); // TODO: errors...

  Py_DECREF(numerator);
  Py_DECREF(denominator);

  $1 = &tmp;  
}

%typemap(out) Fraction {
  // Output typemap: pass two ints into fractions.Fraction() ctor
  $result = PyObject_CallMethod(fractions_module, "Fraction", "ii", $1.numerator, $1.denominator);
}

%inline %{
  struct Fraction {
    int numerator, denominator;
  };

  void fraction_in(const Fraction& fraction) {
    std::cout << fraction.numerator << "/" << fraction.denominator << "\n";
  }

  Fraction fraction_out() {
    Fraction f = {100, 1};
    return f;
  }
%}
```

Mostly this is just two typemaps - one for inputs to C++ functions and one for outputs. They construct a temporary C++ Fraction from the numerator and denominator attributes of the input object and construct a `fractions.Fraction` Python object from our C++ one respectively. Adapting them for other similar fractional types should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it later this week!

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks a lot! One little question though, where do I release the loaded `fractions` module? I now understand the `init` block, but I didn't find any similar "tear down" annotation where I could put it... (sorry for the delay!)

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not sure. I'll see if I can find it. Worst case you could use a `unique_ptr` I guess.

Comment: This might be useful for someone: `%typemap(typecheck, precedence=SWIG_TYPECHECK_DOUBLE) xyz::Fraction { $1 = PyObject_HasAttrString($input, "numerator") && PyObject_HasAttrString($input, "denominator"); }` (took me a while to put it together :)